# Is my MySQL being monitored by monit using nginx?

Tags: mysql, nginx, monit

I'm unsure if my mysql is actually being monitor by monit. See screenshot.
[image: monit screenshot]

As you can see under processes the mysqld process is not being monitored (it failed a sew times first) but under files there is mysql_bin and mysql_rc both of which are OK.

Is it safe to remove the mysql monitoring symbolic link or do i need this anyway?

thanks

Comment: This question is about database administration, not about programming, therefore it is off topic here on SO. The DBA sister site of SO provides support for questions like this one.

Answer (score 0):

Short answer is **no**. Some more info:

That both of the entries in the *File* section are OK does not relate to any kind of working or running application. The *File* section of monit simply checks file state information, such as, but not limited to, last modification time, size, file hashes, etc.

So basically the two OKs in *File* section just tell you that the mysql files are present and have not been changed.

The entry inside *Process* section is what you want to focus an. It checks the presence of a running `mysqld` process on your system. You need to check if the configuration of that entry inside `monitrc` (or included files) is looking for the right parameters. It should watch out for a process using a pidfile and could potentially check if a connection could be established.

See [monit docs on MySQL](https://mmonit.com/monit/documentation/monit.html#MYSQL) and/or paste your monit config for any in-depth help regarding monit.

PS: @Shadow: The question (more likely: the resulting problem) has nothing to do with a DB, but is a question about monitoring.

Comment: Hi boppy, That makes sense. I'll have a look into this and if need more info I'll open a new question.